# How can I put a navigation bar with body border running through the middle?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how best to explain this, but I am essentially looking to put my navigation bar centered top middle with the body border overflowing. This picture is essentially what I am trying to do: https://ibb.co/jvtqdMS

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please provide your current code

Comment: Hey, I don't have any code yet I am not sure how to go about doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

It is what I have in mind for your problem:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 5%; width: 50%; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
      <button style="width: 20%; height:100% ;">test 1</button>
      <button style="width: 20%; height:100% ;">test 2</button>
      <button style="width: 20%; height:100% ;">test 3</button>
      <button style="width: 20%; height:100% ;">test 4</button>

    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: -20px !important;height: 95%; width: 50%; border: 2px black solid; border-radius: 5px; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
      <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
        Body goes here...
      </div>
      <h4 style="bottom:10px; position: absolute; text-align: center;">Footer</h4>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```